# Type for an Object-Array with a "Pick one of each" rule in io-ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'd like to define a type for an array using `io-ts`.

These are the possible values for the array

```js
{ platform: 'A', metric: null }
{ platform: 'B', metric: 'A' }
{ platform: 'B', metric: 'B' }
{ platform: 'B', metric: 'C' }
```

The crux is you should only be able to add one item per `platform` to the array and I have absolutely no clue how you would do that.

Here is what I have right now

```
import * as t from 'io-ts'

export const MyType = t.type({
  // ...other stuff

  metrics: t.array(t.union([
    t.type({ platform: t.literal('A'), metric: t.nullType }),
    t.type({ platform: t.literal('B'), metric: t.literal('A') }),
    t.type({ platform: t.literal('B'), metric: t.literal('B') }),
    t.type({ platform: t.literal('B'), metric: t.literal('C') })
  ]))
})

export type MyType = t.TypeOf<typeof MyType>
```

And some examples of valid/invalid options

```
const var1: MyType = [{ platform: 'A', metric: null }] // Valid
const var2: MyType = [{ platform: 'B', metric: 'A' }] // Valid
const var3: MyType = [{ platform: 'A', metric: null }, { platform: 'B', metric: 'A' }] // Valid
const var4: MyType = [{ platform: 'B', metric: 'A' }, { platform: 'B', metric: 'B' }] // Invalid
```

I was thinking about splitting metrics into two seperate types (one for each platform) but I have no clue if there is a way to specify that you should only be able to add one of each possible values per platform. I did I bunch of googling but I'm not sure what exactly I am looking for. Could anyone point me into the right direction?